# JavaFX / FXML - Get Height of a VBox

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have the following problem. I've got this VBox wrapped in an AnchorPane:

```
<AnchorPane>
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="sidebar" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="150.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"/>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And I want to get the displayed height of this vbox (even after e.g. resizing the Anchorpane around it.) 
 So I tried the following:

```
double height = sidebar.getHeight();
```

but for some reason getHeight() just returns 0. So... how do I get the height of that vbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a several possible reasons, why `getHeight()` returns '0'.

1. Your `VBox` doesn't contain any children.
2. It's not in the `SceneGraph` yet.

Comment: I've just realized that you set the anchor constraints for the vbox. So `sidebar.getHeight()` should return a value equal to the height of the `AnchorPane`. Are you sure you're using the correct reference for sidebar?

Comment: Okay, I've added children to the VBox now. I previously had the getHeight() in the initialize-method of my Controller, there it returned 0. Now I wrote a method that returns the height on button press, there it worked.

Comment: Or 3. The `VBox` simply has not yet been layouted...